# Ember and DataTables Integration

Tags: json, ember.js, datatables

I am attempting to integrate DataTables into an Ember application. I have had success creating a view with hard-coded object data, but I am running into trouble calling the data from a Web Service JSON.

Is there an easy way by just using the built-in "ajaxDT" from dataTables inside of a basic Ember View?

or do I absolutely need to be getting the JSON through an Ember model and then feeding it into dataTables through another method?

I am currently trying a couple attempts, so I will post them if they do/don't work.

If anyone has already figured it out, please let me know.

Comment: My requirement is also to populate Jquery datatable with Ember model data. Could you please share your code if you find the solution?

Comment: I will give +1 if you share your solution.

Comment: @Ashok.N  I stayed away from datatables with ember for now. I found no good sources for integrating it.  The problem is they both can generate DOM dynamically, and they are tricky to control and cause conflicts.  I will let you know if i find a alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am frustrated now. Populating the data table is a common requirement. I am still wondering how `ember` is becoming popular when it is not able to solve minimum things. I thought that life will become easier if I use `Ember`,But in reality it is not the case. Please update the thread if you find any alternative or workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A real simple example of integrating jQuery Datatables with Ember would be to create a component as follows:

```
App.JqueryDatatablesComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  configureDatatables: function(){
    this.$('#example').DataTable();
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vakagu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: this works fine for static templates... however populating a table with ember data, rendering it, and *then* applying jq.datatables to it, is much more complex, as they both will try to manipulate the DOM at the same time.